# Отправка  GET средствами Delphi

Tags: delphi, запрос, get

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, отправить запрос методом `GET` по этим данным:

https://192.170.154.78:8443/bgbilling/balance_sender?login=*****&pswd=*****&mid=8

И обработать полученные данные с сервера

```
<data status="ok" summa="-****.**">Баланс = -****.**</data>
```

Формат полученных данных `XML`.

Проверял методы:

```
idhttp1.get(‘https://192.170.154.78:8443/bgbilling/balance_sender?login=&pswd=&mid=8?id=4&stars=5‘);
```

Выводит ошибку.

Comment: Если сервак редиректит клиента, то свойство HandleRedirects компонента idHTTP должно быть выставлено в TRUE, иначе наша программы вылетит, словив исключение 302, т.к. по умолчанию редирект запрещен

Comment: А как использовать SSL запрос ? не подскажете ?

Comment: к стати забыл написать я поставил HandleRedirects значение true

Comment: что вы называете SSL запрсом?
Любой запрос который начинается на http**s** и есть с SSL

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку адрес https:, то нужно добавить компоненты для работы с SSL.
А ответ обрабатывайте как обычную строку.

То есть примерно это будет выглядеть так:

```
s:=idhttp1.get(‘https://192.170.154.78:8443/bgbilling/balance_sender?login=&pswd=&mid=8?id=4&stars=5‘);
```

В переменной `S` будет Ваш ответ.

Comment: Во первых нам потребуется два компонента с пакета indy, а именно TIdHTTP (Indy Clients) и TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL (Indy I/O Handlers). Если, будете создавать компоненты в run-time, то не забывайте подключать в Uses модули IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL. 
 IdHTTP1.IOHandler:=IdSSLIOHandlerSo cketOpenSSL1; //эта строка в комментариях не нуждается

Comment: Во вторых нам надо библиотеки Openssl. Всего две из целого набора: libeay32.dll и ssleay32.dll. Поэтому можно качать lite версию. Согласно документации библиотеки нужно закинуть в системный каталог винды (папку system32), но я держу их в папке с проектом и рекомендую держать их именно там.

 Ну, а финалом этой "сложной" работы будет успешное выполнение кода:



var
   html:String;
begin
   html:=idHTTP1.Get('https://адрес сайта');
   ShowMessage(html);
end;

Comment: savro Спасибо Большое вы мне очень помогли!