# Как отправить Get запрос на HTTPS

Tags: delphi

Нужно отправить **Get** запрос на **HTTPS**. Как именно это сделать?

Заранее **Спасибо** за ответ ^^

Answer (score 5):

Искать пробовали?
Поиск по сайту дал [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/136510/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-get-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-delphi)

Так же гугл выводит кучу информации, например [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377320/synapse-delphi-https-ssl-get-request):

```
SynHttp.Sock.CreateWithSSL(TSSLOpenSSL);
SynHttp.Sock.SSLDoConnect;
SynHttp.HTTPMethod('GET', 'https://www.google.com/');
Resp.LoadFromStream(SynHttp.Document);
HtmlResponse := Resp.Text;
```